# Cassandra nodes in multiple data centers

Tags: datacenter, cassandra

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/ladis2009/papers/lakshman-ladis2009.pdf : "Cassandra is configured such that each row is replicated across multiple data centers."

So in that case is it good to have almost same number of Cassandra nodes in each data center. If not, would that generate key hotspots?

Answer (score 1):

See answer here: http://n2.nabble.com/Cassandra-nodes-in-multiple-data-centers-tp4125377p4126052.html